# Perl- print hash values while the key is matched

Tags: perl

I am trying to print some hash values using html tags inside Perl code. But what I get instead of values is `1`. This happens when I try to print hash values inside `sub`. Is this the right way ?

```
package shembull;

%rhash= (
    lbl_name  =>  "L",
    lbl_surname =>  "G",
    txt_nameemri    =>  "N",
    txt_surname =>  "M",
    btn_submit  =>  "submit",
);

sub lbl_input {
my $value = @_;
return "<label>".$value."</label>";
}

sub txt_input {
my $value = @_;
return "<textarea>".$value."</textarea>";
}

sub btn_input {
my $value = @_;
return"<button>".$value."</button>";
}

foreach my $tmp (keys %rhash){
    if($tmp =~/lbl/){
        print lbl_input ($rhash{$tmp});
    }
    elsif($tmp =~/txt/){
        print txt_input ($rhash{$tmp});
    }
    elsif($tmp =~/btn/){
        print btn_input ($rhash{$tmp});
    }
}
```

What may e the reason?  Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my $value = @_;
```

This will put the number of elements of `@_` in `$value` - evaluating a list in scalar context returns its number of elements.

You can use this instead:

```
my ($value) = @_;
```

Comment: I always do ``my $value=shift`;``  not sure if that is clearer than the answer given though :)

Comment: Any chance of a translation @mat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783632/oracle-11g-imp-dmp-probleme-connexion-sqldevelopper. It looks like a good enough question but my French is nowhere near as good as your English. If you don't think so, don't worry

Answer (score 0):

could be 
my $value=shift;

@_ in context scalar return the number of items or elements that @_ contains.

here a reference: http://perlmaven.com/scalar-and-list-context-in-perl